# setInterval within react-router onEnter dispatching redux actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm building a "check if user is authenticated, if so, refresh their session every 2 minutes" function, and would like to use it as an onEnter hook in my react-router (v2.8.1) routes that need authentication.

```
const requireAuth = (store, nextState, replace) => {
  const redirectToLogin = (state, cb) => cb({
    pathname: '/login',
    state: { nextPathname: state.location.pathname }
  });

  if (getToken() === null) {
    redirectToLogin(nextState, replace);
  } else {
    const authInterval = setInterval(
      store.dispatch(refreshSession()).catch(() => redirectToLogin(nextState, replace))
    , 120000);
    store.dispatch(setRefreshSessionTimer(authInterval));
  }
};
```

I use this in my routes with `.bind(this, store)` (which for me seems a bit iffy, but it works).

```
<Route
  path='/protected'
  onEnter={requireAuth.bind(this, store)}
/>
```

I also have a clearAuthInterval defined onLeave, but the current problem is that it seems when calling `dispatch(refreshSession().catch())` from inside the setInterval, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` from within chrome, (the error source is `VM{someNumbers}:1`, and when I open it I see `[object Promise]`.

I'm using `redux-thunk` middleware, and my action does return a promise, but I seem to be unable to catch the error somehow, and redirect on error from the `refreshSession` action.

EDIT: setInterval needs a function to call. So `setInterval(() => store.dispatch())` works as I originally expected.

Comment: Solved it. It's nothing to do with redux/react-router, etc.

setInterval needs a function to call, so swapping
setInterval(store.dispatch()) for setInterval(() => store.dispatch()) works perfectly

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it accepted. This might help others in the future that run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval needs a function to call.

```
const authInterval = setInterval(() =>
  store.dispatch(refreshSession()).catch(() => redirectToLogin(nextState, replace))
, 120000);
```

This works the way I expect.